# How to send JSON data from Angular to Java?

Tags: java, angularjs, jackson

I'm working on my web app which treats requests with Java.
I'm using Jackson to deserialize my JSON into an Object, however sometimes I got an Exception  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@53e87867; line: 1, column: 1]`

This is how i'm sending data :

```
$scope.update=function(d) {
    server.put("/mddi/rest/users/user/update", d)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.info = "Success."
    })
    .error(function(msg) {
            $scope.msg = msg;
    });
}
```

My update function is :

```
@Path("/user/update")
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void updateUser(String userData, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        System.out.println("User : " + userData);
        User user = mapper.readValue(userData, User.class);
        userDAO.update(user);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have checked in my browser, data is always sent but in my Java, it happens to userData to be empty. 
I have really no idea about my issue.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try printing out the JSON you got. What comes up?

Comment: @ifly6, When my Jackson doesn't throw Exception, I get my full JSON as String. When it throws Exception, it is just empty. But i'm sure it is always sent from javascript. I would say Java isn't waiting to receive full request before treating it ?

Comment: Your exception tells you that there is no content because the input has ended.

Comment: Yes, because "userData" is empty. Sometimes it is empty, sometimes it isn't. I'm clueless about the reason.

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to send in the browser network?

Comment: @Deepanjan, just my ngModel : {"userID":152,"login":"test","groupe":{"groupeID":4,"name":"MHall","rightLevel":"hall"},"clicked":false,"usines":null,"miniUsines":null,"fluxs":null}

Comment: There is extra character in rightLevel in the json you are passing show may be it is not deserializing.

Comment: @Deepanjan, sorry ? which extra character ? didn't get what you meant :/ The problem isn't really with mapper.readValue, it is that my userData is sometimes empty.

Comment: You copy your json data and paste it in plunker you will find the extra character which makes it empty because its not getting deserialised